# WordPress anti-spam measures

Tags: spam, blog, wordpress

I host a WordPress blog that has been hit with a huge amount of spam in the last three months. I've tried to install several anti-spam plugins that are highly rated, but it doesn't help.

What else can I do or what plugins can I install to stop this wave of spam?

Comment: Can you say more about "it doesn't help"?  Do the plugins not work as advertised, are you having problems configuring them, have the spammers figured out how to defeat them, or what?  Thanks.

Comment: This type of question would be best on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this question really matches the site, nevertheless I'll answer you.

I can recommend you:

- [Stop Spammers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/stop-spammer-registrations-plugin/)
- [WP-reCaptcha](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-recaptcha/)

The first one focuses on stopping the spam at your entire site: your comment section, your login section, your registration section, and your trackback section. The second one just checks whether you are a robot or not, both on your registration form and comment form. I use both, and reduced the spam I'm receiving at a total of 98%.

You should note that the first one documents nearly everything. If somebody logs in and gets rejected due to behaviour that matches him as a spammer - in the view of the plugin -, his/her IP address and the username and the password he/she used will be stored and saved. This can lead to some problems with the privacy policy in some jurisdictions.

Comment: I'd add on to that to switch to requiring approved comments before the comments go live.  Unless you have a very active blog, that, combined with lots of anti-spam measures stacked on top of each other, is pretty effective.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from native WordPress comments to Disqus years ago - it helped *a lot* with spam.

However, Disqus is not without its own special brand of craziness, either.

The Akismet plugin (ships with WP, and is free to use once you get a free API key) helps some with native WP comment spam - but botnets don't care how much they spam you.

Sadly - or, perhaps, happily - often the best way to handle comments is to disallow them. If someone wants to react to what you wrote, they can write a blog post themselves, or comment on Twitter/Facebook/Mastodon/etc (ideally, wherever you can interact back).